# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 13 is different from 1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I was solving the problem of boston house price with linear regression using sklearn.
An error like this occurred along the way:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 13 is different from 1)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = boston.data
y = boston.data

dfX = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = boston.feature_names)
dfy = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = ["Price"] )
df = pd.concat([dfX,dfy],axis =1)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X,y)

x_12 = np.array(dfX["LSTAT"]).reshape(-1,1)  # 12th data in boston.data
y = np.array(dfy["Price"]).reshape(-1,1)

predict = reg.predict(x_12) > Error code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be due to `LinearRegression`'s function `fit` is used on all 13 features of `load_boston` dataset but when using `predict`, you only use 1 feature (`LSTAT`). This seems to cause conflict between the trained model and `predict` input data. You probably need to update your `fit` function so that it only takes in `LSTAT` feature so that it will only expect one feature as input data when using `predict`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

boston = load_boston()
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

# X will now have only data from "LSTAT" column
X = X[:, np.newaxis, boston.feature_names.tolist().index("LSTAT")]

dfX = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ["LSTAT"] )
dfy = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = ["Price"] )
df = pd.concat([dfX,dfy],axis =1)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X, y)

x_12 = np.array(dfX["LSTAT"]).reshape(-1, 1)  # 12th data in boston.data
y = np.array(dfy["Price"]).reshape(-1, 1)

predict = reg.predict(x_12)
```